# Heat kernel inequality on indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading a proof and I can't work out what is going in this inequality:
$$ 
\int_{\mathbb R^n} (P_s1_A)^2dx \leq \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} 1_A(x) \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} p_s(x, y)^2dy\right)^{1/2}dx \right)^2.
$$
where $p_s(x, y)$ is the heat kernel associated to the Laplacian on $\mathbb R^n$ and $A$ is a measurable set of finite measure. I can get this far:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} (P_s1_A)^2dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} p_s(x, y)1_A(y)dy\right)^2dx \leq \int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} p_s(x, y)^21_A(y)dydx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} 1_A(y)\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} p_s(x, y)^2dx\right)dy
$$
So I am sort of close except I want to somehow raise the inner bracket term to $1/2$ and the square the expression. But I also can't seem to apply Jensen's inequality which is the only reasonable guess I can make as to how to finish the argument.

Comment: In the right hand side of your first inequality, I think you have swapped $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Oh right, yes, but there should be no major issue I think? I guess I can always change the variable of integration so that it looks like the inequality I want. I still don't know how to go from there though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from a general inequality concerning $L^p$-norms of functions of two variables.
$$
\Bigl\|\int F(x, y)dy \Bigr\|_{L^2(x)} \leq \int \|F(x,y)\|_{L^2(x)} dy.
$$
This is proven by approximating $F$ by simple functions $\sum c_i(x) {\bf 1}_{A_i}(y)$. The integral becomes a sum and we can use the triangular inequality for the norm.

Comment: Ah right, so in my case $F(x, y) = p_s(x, y)1_A(y)$? On the left hand side I have $||P_s1_A||_{L^2(x)}^2 = || \int F(x, y)dy ||_{L^2(x)}^2 \leq (\int ||F(x, y)||_{L^2(x)} dy)^2$ and $||F(x, y)||_{L^2(x)} = (\int p_s(x, y)^21_A(y)dx)^{1/2} = 1_A(y)(\int p_s(x, y)^2dx)^{1/2}$. Thanks for pointing out inequality, I was under the impression some more heavy handed machinery (like Young's convolution inequality or something) was needed

Comment: Yes, take $F(x,y) = p_s(x,y) 1_A(y)$.